# ASP.Net MVC + Wordpress

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have ASP.Net MVC project. Plus wordpress blog under a subfolder "/Blog".

Now, when I access the URL www.domainname.com/Blog, I get the following error:

"The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map."

I guess the problem is because the Blog url is accessing a .php files (Wordpress) which MVC Routing handler does not understand.

Can you please help? What can be done?

Comment: are you sure that php is installed and configured with IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

In my server admin (Plesk), I had an option to run php as CGI app, FastCGI or ISAPI Extension.

Earlier it was CGI app. So it did not work.

I set it to ISAPI Extension and it worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does your hosting support PHP? It does not look like a routing exception, more like a server config error.